# Will the SQL file generated by Entity Framework include the data content change?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my ASP.NET MVC5 project, I used a code first workflow to build my database and I have a bunch of migration files.

I *did not* delete or create columns in the database **manually**.

The problem is all the data content I populated in the database is **not** in the migration files. For some reasons, I populated the most data content through API, and sometimes I have to modify data content **manually**. Only a few data content was populated by `Seed()` method.

Now it is time to deploy my database to a third-party server, and it requires SQL file.

So I use a

```
update-database -script -SourceMigration:0
```

command in Package Manager to generate all the changes in SQL.

The question is, will this SQL file generated by Entity Framework include the data content change? Or it will be totally empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL file will be generated from migrations files and it will write them out to a .sql file.

The data in `Seed()` will not be included as it's not part of migration files.

You can generate content data from the database as a script with data only (`Types of data to script >> choose Data only`) and run them on the third-party server.

Comment: Seems like this is the only choice. Thank you!